Blanchard Khan Conditions and State Variables in Three Equation NK Model
Suppose we have a three equation NK model based on logarithmic household preferences specified by $$\begin{align*}y_t &= \mathbb{E}[y_{t+1}]-(i_t-\mathbb{E}[\pi_{t+1}]-r_t^n) \\
\pi_t &= \kappa y_t + \beta \mathbb{E}[\pi_{t+1}] \\
i_t &= \phi_{\pi}\pi_t +\phi_y y_t +\varepsilon_t \end{align*}$$
Where $\varepsilon$ and $r_t^n$ are some stationary AR(1) processes.
To determine when this system has a unique stable solution, we can use the Blanchard-Khan conditions. In Gali (2008) page 60, he writes this system in matrix form by first inserting the policy rule into the dynamic IS equation, eliminating $i_t$. The maths of this and the derived stability conditions are clear to me, but I am a little uncertain about how to derive stability conditions when we cannot directly eliminate $i_t$.
Consider the alternative policy rule, $$i_t = \gamma i_{t-1} +(1-\gamma)(\phi_{\pi}\pi_t +\phi_y y_t) +\varepsilon_t , \qquad  \gamma \in (0,1)$$
I am uncertain about whether $i_t$ is a state or control variable. At time $t$, $i_{t-1}$ is a state variable, but does this mean that $i_t$ is a control variable? Or is it also a state since $\varepsilon_t$ is known at time $t$? Without thinking too much, I wrote the system with this new policy rule in the form $$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & -1 \\
    0 & \beta & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbb{E}[y_{t+1}] \\
    \mathbb{E}[\pi_{t+1}] \\
    i_t
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    -\kappa & 1 & 0 \\
    (1-\gamma)\phi_y & (1-\gamma)\phi_{\pi} & \gamma
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    y_t \\
    \pi_t \\
    i_{t-1}
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    r_t^n & \varepsilon_t
\end{bmatrix}$$
Define $$J=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & -1 \\
    0 & \beta & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    -\kappa & 1 & 0 \\
    (1-\gamma)\phi_y & (1-\gamma)\phi_{\pi} & \gamma
\end{bmatrix}$$
Interpreting $i_t$ as a state variable, I would then say that the system has a unique stable solution when two eigenvalues of $J$ lie outside the unit circle and one lies inside. Is this the correct way to determine stability of this system? Additionally, how can I more generally be certain about when a variable is a state or not?
